# React dynamic components missing ReactOwner

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with react 0.14.5

I get this funny error message

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: https://fb.me/react-refs-must-have-owner).

My dynamic generated components have no ReactOwner.

Here are some code

```
'use strict';

var React = require('React');
var SettingsUtil = require('scripts/utils/settingsUtil');
var ChangeAllocationsModalRow = require('./changeAllocationsModalRow.jsx');

var ChangeAllocationsModal = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var branches = SettingsUtil.getOperatingBranches();

    var branchesArray = [];
    _.each(branches, function(enabled, operatingBranch) {
      branchesArray.push({
        operatingBranch: operatingBranch,
        enabled: enabled
      });
    });

    var printOperatingBranches = branchesArray.map(function(value) {
      var refName = 'row-'.concat(value.operatingBranch);
      return (
        <ChangeAllocationsModalRow data={value} ref={refName} key={refName} />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="modal fade" id="changeAllocationsModal" tabIndex="-1">
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-small text-left">
          <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-body">
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    {printOperatingBranches}
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = ChangeAllocationsModal;
```

If I remove ref from ChangeAllocationsModalRow everything "works" (no error).
Why?

Edit:
Changed require('React') to require('react') and now I am getting

> Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs (See ref "row-roughage" in bound  created by ChangeAllocationsModal). Attempts to access this ref will fail.

Removed a React.createFactory and everything works now.

Comment: There is same issue on github https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form/issues/107 - have you seen it?

Comment: A hunch: try changing `var React = require('React')` to `var React = require('react')` (lowercase the second "R") to make sure your system only imports React once.

Comment: Also check the other libraries you are using to see if they are importing a different version of React.  (Do an `npm ls | grep -i react`).  I run into this problem alot with React-Bootstrap.

Comment: var React = require('React') to var React = require('react') helped me to next problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Michelle Tilley var `React = require('React')` to `var React = require('react')` fixed the problem.